# Django admin: best practices for keeping it secure

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm about to release my django app to the world, but I'm worried about the admin tab. What are some best practices for keeping the admin secure?

I saw this[website](https://hackernoon.com/5-ways-to-make-django-admin-safer-eb7753698ac8) . It mentioned changing the admin url among other things. Are there any other best practices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few good methods, try this one from this blog - Limit Admin Access Based on IP - [tech.marksblogg.com](http://tech.marksblogg.com/django-admin-logins.html)

Something less sophisticated like a fake Django admin login screen page [django-admin-honeypot](https://github.com/dmpayton/django-admin-honeypot).

and of course - [It is always better for security to deploy your site behind HTTPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/#ssl-https). Deploy your site behind HTTPS, it's easy to implement and it's free [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/), just choose software and system and you're ready to go.